# Give counterexample to the following claim about invertible homomorphic posets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

In general, it is known that all invertible (bijective) group homomorphisms are group isomorphisms. However the same reasoning need not hold true for invertible poset homomorphisms. That is, not all invertible poset homomorphisms are poset isomorphisms. I'm having trouble coming up with an example that validates this claim - since I'm relatively new to Abstract Algebra. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let $A,B$ be two non-isomorphic $2$-element posets and let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ be bijections. Of course, neither $f$ nor $g$ is an isomorphism. If one of them is a homomorphism your problem is solved.

Comment: By the way, why do you use the group-isomorphism and group-homomorphism tags when there'snothing about groups in your question?

Comment: The question is related to group theory so I used those tags for that reason alone.

Comment: That's what I don't understand: **how** is this question related to group theory??

Comment: When I talk about homomorphisms in general, I am referring to group homomorphisms and the same goes for isomorphisms.

Comment: Then I totally misunderstood your question. I thought it was about poset homomorphisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "In general, it is known that all invertible (bijective) group homomorphisms are group isomorphisms"

This is true for sets and groups, but not for abritrary objects on a category. For example, not all bijective continuous functions have a continuous inverse.

As for the posets counterexample: let $a \to b$ be a poset of two elements with $a \leq b$, and $\{c,d\}$ be a poset where no elements are comparable. Let $f(a) = c, f(b) = d$ and $g(c) = a, g(d) = b$ be inverse functions. In particular, both are bijective. Since $g$ is a homomorphism (the poset has no comparable objects so the condition is satisfied trivially), by your claim its inverse should be a morphism, but $f$ is not: $a \leq b$ would imply $f(a) = c \leq d = f(b)$, but once again, $c$ and $d$ are not comparable.

Comment: @SanjoyTheManjoy I'm not seeing the point of your edit. My comment is not tangential: you said you are just learning about abstract algebra. I also started learning abstract algebra lately and this is one of the biggest misconceptions, given that it holds for modules, groups, sets, vector spaces, etc. I am also not critiquing your post or anything, I am just adding context to the answer.

Comment: It's a clarification I already made on my OP prior to your answer that quoted my original post. Another user asked me how this question pertains to group theory, so I edited my question by discussing group homomorphisms rather than homomorphisms in general so that my question wouldn't be taken down. I do appreciate the clarification though, it is helpful to know for the future.

Comment: I would have suggested changing the tags instead of the post content (or maybe both) but I see what you mean. It's a detail, anyway.